# Traslate this queryset?

Tags: django, mysql-workbench, django-queryset

My query is made in MYSQL I would like to know how to translate it to the ORM django tnhanks you

```
SELECT *,(SELECT count(*)
FROM tesisnueva.donador_desactivar ds
where ds.motivo=1 and
ds.donador_id= dd.id and
date_add(ds.fecha_desactivar, INTERVAL 90 DAY)<now()) as cantidad
FROM tesisnueva.donador_donador dd 
where dd.genero='F';
```

MY MODELS

```
class Donador(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hospital = models.ForeignKey(Hospital, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField(validators=[check_date])
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=False,blank=False)
    genero = models.CharField( max_length=1 , choices = GENERO, default='M')
    grupo_sanguineo = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=GRUPO_SANGRE, default='A')
    factor_RH = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=FACTOR_SANGRE, default='+')
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    activo = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    groups = models.ForeignKey(Group, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Desactivar(models.Model):
    donador = models.ForeignKey(Donador,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    motivo= models.IntegerField()
    fecha_desactivar=models.DateField()
```

Comment: Please share the given related models.

Comment: I read that it can be done with outer ref and with subquery but.I don't understand how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) and use a [**`filter=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate-filter) to filter the related model accordingly:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db.models import Q
from django.utils.timezone import now

Donador.objects.filter(genero='F').annotate(
    cantidad=Count(
        'desactivar',
        filter=Q(motivo=1, fecha_desactivar=now()-timedelta(days=90))
    )
)
```

The `Donador` objects that arise from this queryset have an extra attribute `.cantidad` that contains the number of related `desactivar` objects that satisfy the given filter.

Comment: Van Osen the Donador no contains field fecha_descativar

Comment: this error ocurred. django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'fecha_desactivar' into field. Choices are: activo, desactivar, direccion, donacion, factor_RH, fecha_nacimiento, genero, groups, groups_id, grupo_sanguineo, hospital, hospital_id, id, telefono, user, user_id

Comment: @MauricioRiera: it looks like the name of your field is `desactivar` then (since it is listed in the options), so then it is `Q(motivo=1, desactivar=now()-timedelta(days=90))`. Please *read* the exception messages.